# Understanding types of timer interrupts

Tags: arduino-due, interrupt, timers

I'm learning [this note](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-42301-SAM3-4S-4L-4E-4N-4CM-4C-G-Timer-Counter-TC-Driver_ApplicationNote_AT07898.pdf) about timer's api on [Arduino Due](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue). Interrupt can be attached with the next function:

```
void tc_enable_interrupt(
       Tc * p_tc,
       uint32_t ul_channel,
       uint32_t ul_sources)
```

Where the input parameter ul_sources can be one or more of the following:

> **TC_IER_COVFS** Enables the Counter Overflow Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_LOVRS** Enables the Load Overrun Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_CPAS**  Enables the RA Compare Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_CPBS**  Enables the RB Compare Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_CPCS**  Enables the RC Compare Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_LDRAS** Enables the RA Load Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_LDRBS** Enables the RB Load Interrupt
>
> **TC_IER_ETRGS** Enables the External Trigger Interrupt

I'm more like mobile developer and I don't understand what does all this interrupt types mean.

Comment: The datasheet is a good place to start, http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-11057-32-bit-cortex-m3-microcontroller-sam3x-sam3a_datasheet.pdf, See chap. 36. Timer Counter (TC), pp. 856 and forward. It is really simple. Just a counter and a few registers to match counter value.

Comment: @MikaelPatel, this chapter is to difficult for me.

Comment: At least take a look at Figure 36-6. Waveform Mode, pp. 866. It shows the interrupt flags and where they come from. A Timer is basically a counter with a clock source and a few match/load registers. Interrupts are typically when the counter comes to a specific value such as overflow, contents of A/B match register, etc. It is not rocket science.

Comment: @MikaelPatel, ok thanks. I will take a look. Actually I want to achieve one of this things: A) Timer Interrupt that fires only once; B) Adjustable timer interrupt, so I can modify phase without restarting the timer.

Comment: A) disable the timer interrupt in the ISR, B) adjust the match register in the ISR, are typical methods. Typical ISRs can be found in for instance Cosa Real-Time Timer (RTT) implementation, https://github.com/mikaelpatel/Cosa/blob/master/cores/cosa/Cosa/RTT.cpp#L143, Compare A is used for millis-seconds count update, Compare B is used for one-shot micro-seconds level job scheduling.

Comment: Thank you. I've thought about disabling interrupt in the ISR but it seem to expensive by performance to me.